# How do I process multiple CSV files parallely in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

My application has users who submit csv files using a web application.

A kafka producer reads each CSV records and sends to a kafka topic having 2 partitions and 2 consumers in each partition. Each CSV file can have number of records ranging from 100 - 100,000.

Each consumer reads from same topic and can process 1000 records in 30 secs in average.

So, 4 consumers can process one file of 100,000 records in (100,000/4)*30/1000/60 = 12.5 mins.

The issue is, while one file is processing, the second file has to wait for 12.5 mins, third file has to wait for 25 mins and so on.

How can I manage my partition strategy so that each file is processed parallel and not serially?

Also, if a big file is getting processed, can I somehow process a smaller file which is submitted later ? I am using Java Spring Kafka connector for both producer and consumers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to partition your topic such that you can scale the number of consumers in the consumer group. For example, if you give is 24 partitions then you could have one consumer (which would read across all of them), two consumers (each gets twelve partitions), and so on up to (in this example) 24 consumers each reading from one partition, in parallel.

When you produce the data bear in mind that the key that you set determines which partition the data will get written to, so if you need any processing affinity in the consumers then set this correctly. If it doesn't matter which records a consumer processes then you can leave the key unset and the messages will be written round-robin across all the available partitions.

If you are processing data that the consumers would want to process in order, for example, changes to an invoice and the consuming application would need to have all the events for a particular invoice, then you would key on invoice ID (in this example). If all the records can be processed independently then leave the key null and data will be spread across all partitions evenly by the producer API, even when ingesting a single file.

Comment: Hi Robin. Can you help me with key pattern I can use to achieve this? Please bear in mind, i do not want my consumers to sit idle as well. That means if I have only one file, all the consumers will process some records of the file.